# Unbalanced Cassandra replicas storage

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

In our setup we have 2 DCs, 21 Cassandra nodes in each DC, and a total of 4 replicas per record (in one of the keyspaces) - two replicas per site.
Every Cassandra node is setup with 16 VNodes.
We did not manually set the initial_token for each node in the cluster, rather we let Cassandra decide on the token range distribution.

My problem - when listing the token ranges in our cluster it seems that the replicas are stored in an unbalanced manner.
For instance, this is one of the 672 records displayed ([42 nodes]*[16 VNodes]):

> TokenRange(start_token:-8400100964809109474,
>   end_token:-8379945255976340112, endpoints:[xxx.101.xxx.210,
>   xxx.101.xxx.212, 10.x.108.xxx, xxx.164.xx.157],
>   rpc_endpoints:[xxx.101.xxx.210, xxx.101.xxx.212, 10.x.108.xxx,
>   xxx.164.xx.157],
>   endpoint_details:[EndpointDetails(host:xxx.101.xxx.210,
>   datacenter:ALLNTXDW, rack:RAC1), EndpointDetails(host:xxx.101.xxx.212,
>   datacenter:ALLNTXDW, rack:RAC1), EndpointDetails(host:10.x.108.xxx,
>   datacenter:BOTHWAKY, rack:RAC1), EndpointDetails(host:xxx.164.xx.157,
>   datacenter:BOTHWAKY, rack:RAC1)])

Out of 672 records, every node is assigned exactly 16 times to the first term in the "endpoints" and "rpc_endpoints" tuples (as expected). But the second, third, fourth terms are populated unevenly, causing the cluster to be unbalanced. One of the nodes appears as the fourth term in 28 of the 672 tuples, whereas others appear as few as 4(!) times as the fourth term.

This leads to one of the nodes receiving over 12 percent of the data inserted to the cluster (86 out of 672 assignments in token ranges), whereas some nodes receive half of that (43 out of 672 assignments in token ranges).

Can the token range assignment *for replicas* be controlled?
How do I approach balancing this?

Note: this cluster is production, and is already loaded with many TBs of data. In-fact this problem came to our attention as the space in one of the machines filled up to 98% whereas other machines have as little as 40 percent space used.

Thanks!
Gal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using only 16 vnodes per host is probably not a good idea. Each vnode token will be generated randomly with the expectation that an even balancing will happen with a large enough number of tokens. The lesser number of used vnodes, the higher the variation and possibility of an uneven distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Stefan.
I read in several places that the recommended number is 256.
However, the trade-off is that repair will take a longer time. Already we're running at a slow pace of 8-16 hour repair cycles per node. 
Is there some formula to use to improve the distribution but not something that would kill us performance-wise?

Comment: In theory, using 256 vnodes instead of 16 should only add the overhead of managing 256 repair sessions instead of 16. This will slow down repairs significantly for clusters with little data. However, it shouldn't matter a lot for the cluster size that you described. In theory. ;)

If you're certain that you want to go with 16 vnodes you're probably better off specifying those ranges manually. This allows you to calculate an even distribution yourself instead of generating those ranges manually.

Comment: meant to say: ..generating those ranges _randomly_

Comment: Am I right in assuming that in any case the solution would require taking down the cluster, then applying the changes followed by a full repair of all keyspaces?

Comment: Either that or adding a new DC with the new configuration and decommission the existing DCs one by one. Adding a new DC seems to be the safer way since we're talking about a production system.